# Is there some way to change an Outlook icon?

Tags: windows-xp, calendar, microsoft-outlook-2003

XP.

I use Outlook (2003) a lot and like to have both my Mail and My Calendar open at the same time. I would like to change the Calendar icon that appears in my task bar when both are open, to something more easily recognized. Is this possible?

What I am trying to do is keep the default Outlook icon for the first instance of the program I open, but change the icons for each additional window I open at the same time. For example, I have Outlook mail open. Sometimes I want to have the Calendar open at the same time. I would like to be able to change the Icon for the 2nd instance.

Comment: you wan to change the shortcut icon or the orginal icon

Comment: I want to change the icon that appears in my task bar when both are open. I will edit my question.

Answer (score 1):

I have replaced a handful of program icons using [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) (and [XN Resource Editor](http://www.wilsonc.demon.co.uk/d10resourceeditor.htm) for more recent 64-bit programs).  Outlook is a more complex program than the ones that I have successfully done this with, but you can try and see if it works for you.

Once you have found the icon that you need to replace within OUTLOOK.EXE, try to replace it with a similar icon, with the same [different sizes and types of bitmaps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997636.aspx) as the original.  The easiest way to do this would be to edit the original in an icon editor like [IcoFX](http://icofx.ro/) or [IconWorkshop](http://www.axialis.com/iconworkshop/).

If you try this out with Outlook, please tell me how it goes.  I'm curious.

Comment: @Jason i was going to add this as a addon but stopped back as it requires more manual work :P I am glad you included them

Comment: @subanki: I think that the solutuon that you provided will only work with simpler .exe files, where there is only one main program icon. Outlook.exe contains many different icons, and the one that the OP wants to change is not the main application icon. I did not downvote you, BTW. Cheers.

Comment: @Jason if not exe then what file is he trying to change . BTW it supports dll, cpl, exe, scr, ocx. And by the way should I delete my answer ???

Comment: @subanki: Outlook.exe contains many icons, and it uses different icons for the Taskbar, when you open the different sections in separate windows (Mail, Calendar, Contacts, Tasks, etc).

Comment: Exactly. Can these be changed?

Comment: @Xavierjazz:  Didn't you try what I said in my answer?

Comment: @jason404. Not yet, too pressured. Will do so this week. Thanks, Regards,

Answer (score 0):

- Use  [Icon Changer](http://www.shelllabs.com/)

[image]

- Use Resource hacker, you can change any icon in that

Comment: I don't think icon changer changes application icons, does it?

Comment: No it doesn't actually change the icon of the exe but it puts the respective icon you chose to see, hence works only in your machine . By the way there is another changer that can change exe too , i am searching for it and I will update my answer soon.

Comment: Update to my comment the above mentioned program can change application icon . read it here http://www.shelllabs.com/change_exe_icon.htm

Comment: Thr icon in the taskbar is the same icon that you see in the titlebar

Comment: Why Down-vote this program can change icon of the exe-file as the question asks. It changes the orginal icon file , icon in the titlebar , icon in the taskbar and icon in the tray . I tested it